# alguna otra manera de exportar un Datatable a Excel de una manera mas rapida, sin tener que dibujar cada fila y columna en .net?

Tags: sql, .net, excel, datatable

Tengo un Datatable llamado dtConsolidado que lo traigo desde un procedimiento de sql, esta parte funciona bien pero es muy demorado a la hora de exportar una gran cantidad de registros, alguna manera de hacerlo mas optimo?

```
 Dim m_Excel As New Excel.Application
    m_Excel.Cursor = Excel.XlMousePointer.xlWait
    m_Excel.ScreenUpdating = False
    m_Excel.Visible = True
    Dim objLibroExcel As Excel.Workbook = m_Excel.Workbooks.Add
    objLibroExcel.Worksheets.Add()
    Dim objHojaConsolidado As Excel.Worksheet = objLibroExcel.Worksheets(1)
    Dim objHojaAvance As Excel.Worksheet = objLibroExcel.Worksheets(2)


    With objHojaConsolidado
        .Name = ("HOJA 1")
        .Activate()
        .Cells.Select()
        .Cells.ClearContents()
        ' Seleccionamos la primera celda de la hoja.
        .Range("A1").Select()
        ' Escribimos los nombres de las columnas en la primera
        ' celda de la primera fila de la hoja de cálculo
        Dim fila As Integer = 1
        Dim columna As Integer = 1
        For Each dc As DataColumn In dtConsolidado.Columns
            .Cells(fila, columna) = dc.ColumnName
            columna += 1
        Next
        ' Establecemos los atributos de la fuente para las
        ' celdas de la primera fila.
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, dtConsolidado.Columns.Count)).Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Bold = True
            .Size = 12
        End With
        ' Insertamos los datos en la hoja de cálculo, comenzando por la
        ' fila número 2, ya que la primera fila está ocupada
        ' por el nombre de las columnas.
        fila = 2
        For Each row As DataRow In dtConsolidado.Rows
            ' Primera columna
            columna = 1
            For Each dc As DataColumn In dtConsolidado.Columns
                .Cells(fila, columna) = row(dc.ColumnName)

                ' Siguiente columna
                columna += 1
            Next
            ' Siguiente fila
            fila += 1
        Next
        ' Autoajustamos el ancho de todas las columnas utilizadas.
        .Columns().AutoFit()

    End With
```

Podrian ayudarme por favor , necesito que sea rapido y eficiente este se demora varios minutos exportando.

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente hay dos métodos para exportar datos a un Excel. El primero es utilizar `OleDb` con el driver `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`. Se utiliza como un proveedor de datos más pudiendo hacer un `Insert`, aunque es una solución poco utilizada pues hay muchos matices que hace que su configuración sea compleja.

El segundo es utilizar alguna librería. La más odiada por muchos es la propia de Office, la famosa `Interop`, la que has usado tu mismo. La más ágil es [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus), que puedes instalar desde NuGet y es gratuita. Con pocas líneas podrás exportar todo el `Datatable`.

```
Dim archivoExcel As New FileInfo("C:\exportacion\export.xlsx")
Using package As New ExcelPackage(archivoExcel)
    Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Hoja1")
    ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtConsolidado, True)
    package.Save()
End Using
```

Al margen de exportar los datos, podrás cambiar el aspecto de la exportación. En [este enlace](https://riptutorial.com/epplus) tienes múltiples ejemplos.